# how to solve SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException?

Tags: java

00000182 SystemOut     O ==== Inside updateValidation exceptionStackTrace = com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, SQLERRMC=XHAZMAT1;000098D401, DRIVER=4.21.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try checking for any SQL constraints like indexes with name - XHAZMAT1 on the table you are updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the SQL error message SQLERRMC in the console which is throwing update validation error. Seems like you are updating a record in database that is having any constraints related to indexes etc. 
Also, you can look for XHAZMAT1 on the table you are updating.